# Run-time error: '1004' on Range AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do with VBA - filter table with array and delete rows.
My array has 4 elements (changed in a loop to have 5 different sets). Column which is being filtered has 5 elements. I want to get just 1. This is inside a loop which will create 5 reports, each filtered for different element based on column 29.

If in debugging mode I filter that column manually and skip that line I have second, identical error 5 lines below when trying to clear all filters back again.

This are lines 765 and 770 out of part of 788. Everything else runs smoothly.

FilterOutArray - array with 4 elements (Variant/String each). Column 29 has 5 different values, no blanks

I've tried to refer "Criteria1" with string, to see if filtering one elements works, but not.

```
'Run-time error: '1004' on row below
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1).Cells(29, LastRow)).AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=FilterOutArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

'Run-time error: '1004' on row below
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1).Cells(29, 9999)).AutoFilter Field:=29
```

Comment: what do you expect by `Range(Cells(1, 1).Cells(29, LastRow))`? Shouldn't it be `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(29, LastRow))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1).Cells(29, LastRow)) ...
```

Should be a comma, and not a dot. Like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(29, LastRow)) ...
```

The "interesting" part is that something like this: `Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2).Address` is a valid syntax, giving the address of the corresponding cell, 1 column right and 1 row down, e.g. `B2`.

Anyway, in general, consider [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). And the "correct" way to write ranges defined by 2 cells is something like this:

```
With Worksheets(1)
    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 5))
End With
```

Comment: Will make a comment on rather than posting an answer... qualify all references, Bartek.  If `ActiveSheet.Range()` were to read `Sheets(1).Range()`, you'd be in a slightly different scenario, since `ActiveSheet` is inferred by the system for each of your `cells()` references... `Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(),Sheets(1).Cells())` would be appropriate, though a `With-statement` typically makes it look cleaner.